# Is there any problem that can't be solved by brute force approach?

Tags: algorithm, backtracking, brute-force

Assuming that there is no time/space limitation(just assuming), brute force or backtracking solutions always exist on any problems? 
I'm just wondering....

Comment: Are you limiting yourself to turing machines?  If so then no there are an uncountable number of non-computable functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem is a famous example. In general, this category of "unsolvable" programs is called "[undecidable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)"

Comment: If there are *no* time limitations, couldn't you wait forever to see if the machine halted?  The thing about the Halting Problem is that a decision has to be made in a finite amount of time.

Comment: @ScottHunter it's not a matter of limitations, it's a matter of correctness. The halting problem is undecidable because there is no such program that can even correctly predict the outcome for all possible programs, even if we ignore the issue of "waiting forever".

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In formal denotational semantics, programs that never terminate are modeled as functions that return the value "top" in a lattice or complete partial order where all the other values are actual results. The resulting math has produced important results about what can and can't be represented in computer languages and type systems. Scott seems to have the essence of this idea intuitively.  If we _could_ wait forever, we could characterize "top" exactly as he says. Since we can't, we define it as undefined and carry on :-)